# How can i get any information like lat,long when i touch on MKMapView in iPhone/iPad?

Tags: ios, ios4, mkmapview

I have a mapView using xib file now when i touch in the mapview i want the latitude and longitude of that particular area so there any whey or any sample code which help me in this task.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With iOS 3.2 or greater, it's probably better and simpler to use a `UIGestureRecognizer` with the map view instead of trying to subclass it and intercepting touches manually.

First, add the gesture recognizer to the map view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureHandler:)];
tgr.delegate = self;  //also add <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to @interface
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
[tgr release];
```

Next, implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` and return `YES` so your tap gesture recognizer can work at the same time as the map's (otherwise taps on pins won't get handled automatically by the map):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
        :(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Finally, implement the gesture handler:

```
- (void)tapGestureHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tgr
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [tgr locationInView:mapView];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate 
        = [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

    NSLog(@"tapGestureHandler: touchMapCoordinate = %f,%f", 
        touchMapCoordinate.latitude, touchMapCoordinate.longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its kind of a tricky thing to be done.

First you need to subclass mkmapview

in

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method you can find the location of touch and then using this method

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view
```

you can find lat and long..

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3:

```
func tapGestureHandler(_sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = _sender.location(in: mapView)
    let touchMapCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom:mapView)

    print("latitude: \(touchMapCoordinate.latitude), longitude: \(touchMapCoordinate,longitude)")
}
```