# UIGestureRecognizer on MKOverlayView not firing action

Tags: iphone, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to make some polygons (MKOverlayViews) tappable by adding a gesture recognizer to each of them.

I have an NSArray containing KMLParsers (from the KMLViewer sample code).

```
-(MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{

     for (NSString *key in kmls) {

          KMLParser *kml2=[kmls objectForKey:key];
          MKOverlayView *oView;

          if ( (oView = [kml2 viewForOverlay:overlay]) ) {

               if (layerNumber == 8) {
                    NSLog(@"8");
                    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                                   action:@selector(showZoneText:)];
                    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
                    [oView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
                    [tap release];
               }
               return oView;
          }
     }
     return nil;
}
```

This code logs 8, therefore the "if" block is executed, and the layer number 8 is displayed.

However, the "showZoneText" method is never fired when I tap the polygons (an NSLog in that method never shows in the console).

```
-(void)showZoneText:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"show");
}
```

Any help on this?

thanks,

G.

Comment: Please include the method declaration for `showZoneText:` - does it have a parameter?

Comment: I don't know how to get a UIGestureRecognizer to work in an MKOverlayView.  An alternative is to attach the GR to the map view and get the touch point (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284760/467105) and then figure out if that point is in some overlay (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4354250/467105).

Comment: The showZoneText method did fire when I attached the gesture recognizer to the MKMapView instead of the KMOverlayView. I'll continue with this approach then. Thx.