# Is CGPoint in MKPolygonView?

Tags: ios, mkoverlay

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect which `MKOverlayView` (actually `MKPolygonView`) was tapped and then change its color.

I got it running with this code:

```
- (void)mapTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    MKMapView *mapView = (MKMapView *)recognizer.view;
    MKPolygonView *tappedOverlay = nil;
    for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in mapView.overlays)
    {
        MKPolygonView *view = (MKPolygonView *)[mapView viewForOverlay:overlay];

        if (view){
            // Get view frame rect in the mapView's coordinate system
            CGRect viewFrameInMapView = [view.superview convertRect:view.frame toView:mapView];
            // Get touch point in the mapView's coordinate system
            CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:mapView];
            // Check if the touch is within the view bounds
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(viewFrameInMapView, point))
            {

                tappedOverlay = view;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if([[tappedOverlay fillColor] isEqual:[[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]]){
        [listOverlays addObject:tappedOverlay];
        tappedOverlay.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    }
    else{
        [listOverlays removeObject:tappedOverlay];
        tappedOverlay.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    }
    //tappedOverlay.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];

}
```

Which works but sometimes, depending where I tap it gets wrong which `MKPolygonView` was tapped. I suppose because `CGRectContainsPoint` doesnt calculate properly the area, since it's not a rectangle it's a Polygon.

What other methods there are to do this? I tried `CGPathContainsPoint` but I get worse results.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354130/how-to-determine-if-an-annotation-is-inside-of-mkpolygonview-ios/4354250#4354250?  That also calls CGPathContainsPoint but uses the CLLocationCoordinate2D of the touch (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284760/467105 for how you can do that).  Otherwise, show the code you tried with CGPathContainsPoint.

Comment: I was using the wrong way 'CGPathContainsPoint', I had to convert it to the right point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ana Karenina, that pointed out the right way, this is how you have to convert the gesture so that the method `CGPathContainsPoint`' works right.

```
- (void)mapTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

MKMapView *mapView = (MKMapView *)recognizer.view;

MKPolygonView *tappedOverlay = nil;
int i = 0;
for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in mapView.overlays)
{
    MKPolygonView *view = (MKPolygonView *)[mapView viewForOverlay:overlay];

    if (view){
        CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:mapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate =
        [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

        MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(touchMapCoordinate);

        CGPoint polygonViewPoint = [view pointForMapPoint:mapPoint];
        if(CGPathContainsPoint(view.path, NULL, polygonViewPoint, NO)){
            tappedOverlay = view;
            tappedOverlay.tag = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    i++;
}

if([[tappedOverlay fillColor] isEqual:[[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]]){
    [listOverlays addObject:tappedOverlay];
    tappedOverlay.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
}
else{
    [listOverlays removeObject:tappedOverlay];
    tappedOverlay.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
}
//tappedOverlay.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];

}
```