# Detecting touches on MKOverlay in iOS7 (MKOverlayRenderer)

Tags: ios, touch, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I have an MKMapView with possibly hundreds of polygons drawn. Using MKPolygon and MKPolygonRenderer as one is suppose to on iOS7.

What I need is a way of acting upon the user touching one of the polygons. They represent an area on the map with a certain population density for example.
On iOS6 the MKOverlays were drawn as MKOverlayViews so touch detection was more straightforward. Now using renderers I don't really see how this is suppose to be done.

I'm not sure this will help or is even relevant but as a reference I'll post some code:

This adds all the MKOverlays to the MKMapView using mapData.

```
-(void)drawPolygons{
    self.polygonsInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *polygons = [self.mapData valueForKeyPath:@"polygons"];

    for(NSDictionary *polygonInfo in polygons){
        NSArray *polygonPoints = [polygonInfo objectForKey:@"boundary"];
        int numberOfPoints = [polygonPoints count];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinates = malloc(numberOfPoints * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++){
            NSDictionary *pointInfo = [polygonPoints objectAtIndex:i];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D point;
            point.latitude = [[pointInfo objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
            point.longitude = [[pointInfo objectForKey:@"long"] floatValue];

            coordinates[i] = point;
        }

        MKPolygon *polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfPoints];
        polygon.title = [polygonInfo objectForKey:@"name"];
        free(coordinates);
        [self.mapView addOverlay:polygon];
        [self.polygonsInfo setObject:polygonInfo forKey:polygon.title]; // Saving this element information, indexed by title, for later use on mapview delegate method
    }
}
```

Then there is the delegate method for returning a MKOverlayRenderer for each MKOverlay:

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{
    /* ... */

    MKPolygon *polygon = (MKPolygon*) overlay;
    NSDictionary *polygonInfo = [self.polygonsInfo objectForKey:polygon.title]; // Retrieving element info by element title
    NSDictionary *colorInfo = [polygonInfo objectForKey:@"color"];

    MKPolygonRenderer *polygonRenderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:polygon];

    polygonRenderer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:[[colorInfo objectForKey:@"red"] floatValue]
                                               green:[[colorInfo objectForKey:@"green"] floatValue]
                                                blue:[[colorInfo objectForKey:@"blue"] floatValue]
                                               alpha:[[polygonInfo objectForKey:@"opacity"] floatValue]];

    return polygonRenderer;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: How is touch detection on overlays in iOS 6 "more straightforward"?  What approach are you using in iOS 6?

Comment: MKOverlayViews I'd guess

Comment: I don't know what the IOS7 way is Im afraid

Comment: iOS6 draws overlays as MKOverlayViews. You can always add gesture recognizers to views. You can't do that in iOS7 as there is no view to add the gesture to. That's what I meant.

Comment: @manecosta, Even though MKOverlayViews are subclasses of UIViews, I have never had success getting gesture recognizers to actually work with them.  Adding them and assigning a target has no effect in my experience.

Comment: @Anna Well, I never actually tried that, I just assumed it would be an option. Anyway, I've done it, going through Overlays and testing with CGPathContainsPoint

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've done it.

Thanks to **incanus** and **Anna**!

Basically I add a TapGestureRecognizer to the MapView, convert the point tapped to map coordinates, go through my overlays and check with CGPathContainsPoint.

Adding TapGestureRecognizer. I did that trick of adding a second double tap gesture, so that the single tap gesture isn't fired when doing a double tap to zoom on map. If anyone knows a better way, I'm glad to hear!

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleMapTap:)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
tap2.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
tap2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tap2]; // Ignore single tap if the user actually double taps
```

Then, on the tap handler:

```
-(void)handleMapTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)tap{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [tap locationInView:self.mapView];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D tapCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:tapPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
    MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(tapCoord);
    CGPoint mapPointAsCGP = CGPointMake(mapPoint.x, mapPoint.y);

    for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in self.mapView.overlays) {
        if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]){
            MKPolygon *polygon = (MKPolygon*) overlay;

            CGMutablePathRef mpr = CGPathCreateMutable();

            MKMapPoint *polygonPoints = polygon.points;

            for (int p=0; p < polygon.pointCount; p++){
                MKMapPoint mp = polygonPoints[p];
                if (p == 0)
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
                else
                    CGPathAddLineToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
            }

            if(CGPathContainsPoint(mpr , NULL, mapPointAsCGP, FALSE)){
                // ... found it!
            }

            CGPathRelease(mpr);
        }
    }
}
```

I could ask for the MKPolygonRenderer which already has the "path" property and use it, but for some reason it is always nil. I did read someone saying that I could call invalidatePath on the renderer and it does fill the path property but it just seems wrong as the point is never found inside any of the polygons. That is why I rebuild the path from the points. This way I don't even need the renderer and just make use of the MKPolygon object.

Comment: A worthwhile optimization would be to only run this check for `MKOverlay`s that are in view. I'm not sure how best to tell when an `MKOverlay` leaves the visible bounds, though, which is why I posted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147789/how-can-i-tell-when-an-mkoverlay-is-no-longer-within-view

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATED** (For **Swift 3 & 4**) I'm not sure why people are adding a UIGestureRecognizer to the mapView when mapView already has a number of gesture recognizers running.  I found that these methods inhibit the normal functionality of the mapView, in particular, tapping on an annotation.  Instead, I'd recommend subclassing the mapView and overriding the touchesEnded method.  We can then use the methods others have suggested in this thread and use a delegate method to tell the ViewController to do whatever it needs to do.  The "touches" parameter has a set of UITouch objects that we can use:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol MapViewTouchDelegate: class {
    func polygonsTapped(polygons: [MKPolygon])
}

class MyMapViewSubclass: MapView {

    weak var mapViewTouchDelegate: MapViewTouchDelegate?

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

       if let touch = touches.first {
           if touch.tapCount == 1 {
               let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
               let locationCoordinate = self.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: self)
               var polygons: [MKPolygon] = []
               for polygon in self.overlays as! [MKPolygon] {
                   let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: polygon)
                   let mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(locationCoordinate)
                   let viewPoint = renderer.point(for: mapPoint)
                   if renderer.path.contains(viewPoint) {
                       polygons.append(polygon)                        
                   }
                   if polygons.count > 0 {
                       //Do stuff here like use a delegate:
                       self.mapViewTouchDelegate?.polygonsTapped(polygons: polygons)
                   }
               }
           }
       }

    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

Don't forget to set the ViewController as the mapViewTouchDelegate.  I also found it handy to make an extension for MKPolygon:

```
import MapKit
extension MKPolygon {
    func contain(coor: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        let polygonRenderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: self)
        let currentMapPoint: MKMapPoint = MKMapPoint(coor)
        let polygonViewPoint: CGPoint = polygonRenderer.point(for: currentMapPoint)
        if polygonRenderer.path == nil {
          return false
        }else{
          return polygonRenderer.path.contains(polygonViewPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

Then the function can be a little cleaner and the extension may be helpful somewhere else.  Plus it's swifty-ier!

```
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {
        if touch.tapCount == 1 {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            let locationCoordinate = self.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: self)            
            var polygons: [MKPolygon] = []
            for polygon in self.overlays as! [MKPolygon] {
                if polygon.contains(coordinate: locationCoordinate) {
                    polygons.append(polygon)
                }
            }
            if polygons.count > 0 {
            //Do stuff here like use a delegate:
                self.mapViewTouchDelegate?.polygonsTapped(polygons: polygons)
            }
        }
    }

    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

Comment: This works well, but if the user taps on an annotation, it still triggers and I can't figure out how to cancel it?

Comment: Hugely helpful! For polylines, extend MKPolyline, and in func contains(), add renderer.path.copy(strokingWithWidth:

Comment: Apple doc on `MKMapVIew` states "Although you should not subclass the MKMapView class itself..."

Comment: @Mojo66 it's been a while since I wrote this but can you verify? I don't even work on this project so I don't have access to the code - but if so I'll update the answer to use a return or else statement as a possibility for those who don't want annotations to be tap-able.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a solution that is similar to @manecosta, but it uses existing Apple APIs to detect intersection more easily.

Create an MKMapRect from the tap location in the View. I used 0.000005 as the lat/long delta to represent a user's touch.

```
    CGPoint tapPoint = [tap locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D tapCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:tapPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
    MKCoordinateRegion tapCoordinateRection = MKCoordinateRegionMake(tapCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.000005, 0.000005));
    MKMapRect touchMapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(tapCoordinateRection);
```

Search through all MapView overlays and use the 'intersectsMapRect:' function to determine if your current overlay intersect w/ the MapRect you created above.

```
    for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in self.mapView.overlays) {
        if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]){
            MKPolyline *polygon = (MKPolyline*) overlay;
            if([polygon intersectsMapRect:touchMapRect]){
                NSLog(@"found polygon:%@",polygon);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This also allows you to create a nice buffer so that the user doesn't have to hit the polygon exactly, which is nice for narrow overlays.

Comment: Sorry - but this one gives me this error on this line:              MKMapRect touchMapRect=MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(tapCoordinateRection); "declaration of function 'MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion' is invalid in C99"

Comment: @JakobPipenbringMikkelsen - Google brought me here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270268/convert-mkcoordinateregion-to-mkmaprect

Comment: Doesn't help for complicated geometries as it really just creates a square around your overlays

Comment: The idea of using a buffer (0.000005 degrees in your example) is a good idea to make things easier to touch, but it shouldn't be done in **map** coordinates. It should be done in screen **points**, which represents a consistent measure of a tap's closeness to what the user intended.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my way in Swift

```
@IBAction func revealRegionDetailsWithLongPressOnMap(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began { return }
    let touchLocation = sender.locationInView(protectedMapView)
    let locationCoordinate = protectedMapView.convertPoint(touchLocation, toCoordinateFromView: protectedMapView)
    //println("Taped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)")


    var point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(locationCoordinate)
    var mapRect = MKMapRectMake(point.x, point.y, 0, 0);

    for polygon in protectedMapView.overlays as! [MKPolygon] {
        if polygon.intersectsMapRect(mapRect) {
            println("found")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I originally used your method but I found that converting the locationCoordinate to mapRect did not accurately work.  It was close, but not close enough for detecting within the points I needed (a city).  Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to able to determine this using the APIs that Apple provides. The best you could do with MapKit would be to maintain a separate database of all of your polygon coordinates *as well as* the order that the rendered versions are stacked. Then, when the user touches a point, you could do a spatial query on your secondary data to find the polygon(s) in question combined with the stacking order to determine which one they touched.

An easier way to do this if the polygons are relatively static would be to create a map overlay in [TileMill](http://tilemill.com) with its own interactivity data. Here is an example map that contains interactivity data for countries:

https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zmy97flj/page.html

Notice how some name & image data is retrieved when moused over in the web version. Using the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), which is an open source MapKit clone, you can read that same data out on arbitrary gestures. An example app showing this is here:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-example

That solution might work for your problem and is pretty lightweight as compared to a secondary database and just-in-time calculation of the area touched.

Comment: The first sentence isn't quite accurate (you _can_ use the built-in apis to do this -- it's just not as easy as it could be).  Add a tap gesture recognizer to the map view to detect the touched coordinate and then loop through the polygon overlays themselves (which act as the "database of polygon coordinates") and using CGPathContainsPoint.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524718/is-cgpoint-in-mkpolygonview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014926/detecting-a-point-in-a-mkpolygon-broke-with-ios7-cgpathcontainspoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'm going to use that approach of adding a tap recognizer and then figure out which polygon was touched. Thanks Anna for that CGPathContainsPoint, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering to use both overlay and pin Annotation.
I get the touch from the pin associated to the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR SWIFT 2.1 Find a point/coordinate in a Polygon**

Here is the logic, without tap gestures, to find an annotation inside a polygon.

```
 //create a polygon
var areaPoints = [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.911864, 8.062454),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.912351, 8.068247),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.908536, 8.068376),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.910159, 8.061552)]


func addDriveArea() {
    //add the polygon
    let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &areaPoints, count: areaPoints.count)
    MapDrive.addOverlay(polygon) //starts the mapView-Function
}

  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {


    if overlay is MKPolygon {

        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        renderer.lineWidth = 2 

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(50.917627), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(8.069562))

        let mappoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate)
        let point = polygonView.pointForMapPoint(mappoint)
        let mapPointAsCGP = CGPointMake(point.x, point.y);

        let isInside = CGPathContainsPoint(renderer.path, nil, mapPointAsCGP, false)

        print("IsInside \(isInside)") //true = found

        return renderer
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way of checking as the renderer.path is usually equal to nil at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@davidrynn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42906860/2158024) i've accomplished a more dynamic and updated result.

**Swift 5**

*Subclass MKMapView:*

```
public class MapView: MKMapView {

public var mapViewProtocol: MapViewProtocol?

public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {

        if touch.tapCount == 1 {

            let touchLocation: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            let locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: self)

            var mkCircleList: [MKCircle] = self.overlays.compactMap { $0 as? MKCircle }
            mkCircleList = mkCircleList.filter { $0.contains(locationCoordinate) }
            if !mkCircleList.isEmpty {

                self.mapViewProtocol?.didTapMKCircles(self, mkCircleList)
            }

            var mkMultiPolygonList: [MKMultiPolygon] = self.overlays.compactMap { $0 as? MKMultiPolygon }
            mkMultiPolygonList = mkMultiPolygonList.filter { $0.contains(locationCoordinate) }
            if !mkMultiPolygonList.isEmpty {

                self.mapViewProtocol?.didTapMKMultiPolygons(self, mkMultiPolygonList)
            }

            var mkPolygonList: [MKPolygon] = self.overlays.compactMap { $0 as? MKPolygon }
            mkPolygonList = mkPolygonList.filter { $0.contains(locationCoordinate) }
            if !mkPolygonList.isEmpty {

                self.mapViewProtocol?.didTapMKPolygons(self, mkPolygonList)
            }

            var mkMultiPolylineList: [MKMultiPolyline] = self.overlays.compactMap { $0 as? MKMultiPolyline }
            mkMultiPolylineList = mkMultiPolylineList.filter { $0.contains(locationCoordinate) }
            if !mkMultiPolylineList.isEmpty {

                self.mapViewProtocol?.didTapMKMultiPolylines(self, mkMultiPolylineList)
            }

            var mkPolylineList: [MKPolyline] = self.overlays.compactMap { $0 as? MKPolyline }
            mkPolylineList = mkPolylineList.filter { $0.contains(locationCoordinate) }
            if !mkPolylineList.isEmpty {

                self.mapViewProtocol?.didTapMKPolylines(self, mkPolylineList)
            }

            //TODO
            //var mkTileOverlayList: [MKTileOverlay] = self.overlays.compactMap { $0 as? MKTileOverlay }
            //mkTileOverlayList = mkTileOverlayList.filter { $0.contains(locationCoordinate) }


            self.mapViewProtocol?.didTapMap(self, locationCoordinate)
        }
    }

    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

}

After that i created multiple extensions for each mkOverlay type:

*MKKCircle*

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

extension MKCircle {

    func contains(_ coordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {

        let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(circle: self)
        let currentMapPoint: MKMapPoint = MKMapPoint(coordinate)
        let viewPoint: CGPoint = renderer.point(for: currentMapPoint)
        if renderer.path == nil {

            return false
        } else {

            return renderer.path.contains(viewPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

*MKMultiPolygon*

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension MKMultiPolygon {

    func contains(_ coordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {

        return self.polygons.filter { $0.contains(coordinate2D) }.isEmpty ? false : true
    }
}
```

*MKMultiPolyline*

```
    import Foundation
import MapKit

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension MKMultiPolyline {

    func contains(_ coordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {

        return self.polylines.filter { $0.contains(coordinate2D) }.isEmpty ? false : true
    }
}
```

*MKPolygon*

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

extension MKPolygon {

    func contains(_ coordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {

        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: self)
        let currentMapPoint: MKMapPoint = MKMapPoint(coordinate2D)
        let viewPoint: CGPoint = renderer.point(for: currentMapPoint)
        if renderer.path == nil {

            return false
        } else {

            return renderer.path.contains(viewPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

*MKPolyline*

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

extension MKPolyline {

    func contains(_ coordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {

        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: self)
        let currentMapPoint: MKMapPoint = MKMapPoint(coordinate2D)
        let viewPoint: CGPoint = renderer.point(for: currentMapPoint)
        if renderer.path == nil {

            return false
        } else {

            return renderer.path.contains(viewPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

*And finally create and implement the protocol:*

```
    public protocol MapViewProtocol {

    func didTapMKPolygons(_ mapView: MKMapView, _ mkPolygons: [MKPolygon])

    func didTapMKCircles(_ mapView: MKMapView, _ mkCircles: [MKCircle])

    func didTapMKPolylines(_ mapView: MKMapView, _ mkPolylines: [MKPolyline])

    func didTapMKMultiPolygons(_ mapView: MKMapView, _ mkMultiPolygons: [MKMultiPolygon])

    func didTapMKMultiPolylines(_ mapView: MKMapView, _ mkMultiPolylines: [MKMultiPolyline])

    func didTapMap(_ mapView: MKMapView, _ clLocationCoordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
}
```