# Objective-C add MKOverlay to map view animated fade in

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I've been trying to add an MKOverlay to a map with animation. I'm trying to make it fade in when it's added and fade out when it's removed. Could this be done by created a custom overlay class or overlay view class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 7 you could achieve this even with the new `MKOverlayRenderer`. It has an `alpha` [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayRenderer_class/Reference/Reference.html) which you could animate by setting up a timer to repeatedly change its value and call `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:zoomScale:`.

Answer (score 0):

This is trickier in iOS 7 and above since the overlays aren't represented with views anymore, but rather drawn with renderers (either using the stock ones or rendering yourself in a provided `CGContext` in the delegate).

Whatever you do here will be rendered on a tiled basis, which could lead to differences in appearance across you map view.

You can read more on this here: https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/issues/39