# How can I tell when an MKOverlay is no longer within view?

Tags: ios, geolocation, mapkit

[`MKMapViewDelegate`'s `mapView:rendererForOverlay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3arendererForOverlay%3a) fires when an `MKOverlay`'s `boundingMapRect` enters the visible bounds of the `MKMapView`.

Is there an equivalent delegate method that is fired when the `MKOverlay` leaves the map view's visible bounds? Or do I have to do this math myself?

Comment: There's no such delegate method.  A simple initial approach would be to use the MKMapRectIntersectsRect function with the overlay's boundingMapRect and the visibleMapRect in the regionDidChangeAnimated delegate method.  This assumes the overlay is somewhat rectangular.  If the overlay is a very irregular shape, MKMapRectIntersectsRect will give a false positive.