# Getting the frame of a MKOverlayRenderer is possible?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

Actually, I'm trying to remove the deprecated code from my app (Modifying the target deployment from iOS6 to iOS7) and I'm looking for alternatives. Here is the old code:

```
- (void) mapTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CMELog(@"mapTapped");
    if (sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        return;

    CGPoint mapTouchPoint = [sender locationInView:mainMapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapTouchCoord = [mainMapView convertPoint:mapTouchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mainMapView];
    MKMapPoint touchMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(mapTouchCoord);
    CMELog(@"touchMapPoint: x:%f, y:%f", touchMapPoint.x, touchMapPoint.y);

    // this is where things can get inefficient if you have loads of overlayViews that aren't even visible!
    for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in self.mainMapView.overlays)
    {
        MKOverlayView *overlayView = [self.mainMapView viewForOverlay:overlay];
        CGSize overlayViewSize = overlayView.frame.size;
        CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:overlayView];
        // check to see if the point is within the overlay bounding box first
        if (touchPoint.x > 0 && touchPoint.x < overlayViewSize.width && touchPoint.y > 0 && touchPoint.y < overlayViewSize.height)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I replaced the first line in the loop by the following:

```
MKOverlayRenderer *rendererOverlay = [self.mainMapView rendererForOverlay:overlay];
```

But I could not find how to get the frame of the render overlay. Any idea please?

Comment: What was the purpose of the old code?  Is sender a gesture recognizer?  What view was it added to?  What do you do with touchPoint?  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858108/detecting-touches-on-mkoverlay-in-ios7-mkoverlayrenderer

Comment: You want to know which overlay was touched, right?  See the linked answer.  You don't need the overlay's "frame".

Comment: Yep, you're right it worked.