# Detect what route the user tap on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I have a project where I show directions between current location and another location on a map (MapKit)

All works well. And I can get alternative routes.

```
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = YES;
```

But when the user tap on a route I show an annotation with distance and some other info. I want to pass this spesific route to another view. How can I achieve that? Like the original Map app on iOS. I can get different routes, and tap on a route to get direction details.

I have googled a lot, and the closest example is this:

```
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {        
// Now handle the result
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"There was an error getting your directions");
    return;
}

_currentRoute = [response.routes firstObject];
```

But `_currentRoute` is the first one. I want to let the user select `currentRoute` on tap on the map.

Comment: You should detect touches on MKOverlay. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858108/detecting-touches-on-mkoverlay-in-ios7-mkoverlayrenderer

Comment: But I cannot see how my tap can identify a route, from MKRoute object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Not so elegant, but it does the job.

1. Make an ivar - `NSMutableArray *routeArray` in the header file.

I also have a MKMapView outlet in my header.

2. In my getDirections method, I tagged the MKMapView instance with a counter and added the route object to the routeArray.

When the delegate for making the Annotation is run, I can tag the anntotationView with the mapView.tag.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

3. When I tap on the annotation:

   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

I pass the view.tag to my segue.

```
    NSLog(@"Counter tag: %ld", (long)view.tag);
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detaljer" sender:view];
```

4. I can then pass my selected route to my new view.

   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
   WeatherTableViewController *routeController =
   [segue destinationViewController];
   long row = [sender tag];

   MKRoute *route = routeArray[row];
   routeController.selectedRoute = route;
   }