# Detecting touches on mkoverlay

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm drawing overlays based on directions. I draw from route a to route b and then route b to route c.

I would like to detect if the overlay is tapped anywhere on mkoverlay.

I used this example [Detecting touches on MKOverlay in iOS7 (MKOverlayRenderer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858108/detecting-touches-on-mkoverlay-in-ios7-mkoverlayrenderer)

and converted it to swift.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {
        if touch.tapCount == 1 {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            let locationCoordinate = self.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: self)

            let mapPoint: MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(locationCoordinate)
            let mapPointAsCGP = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(mapPoint.x), y: CGFloat(mapPoint.y))
            for overlay: MKOverlay in self.overlays {
                if (overlay is MKPolygon) {
                    let polygon: MKPolygon? = (overlay as? MKPolygon)
                    let mpr: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
                    let polygonPoints = polygon?.points
                    let polygonPointCount = Int((polygon?.pointCount)!)
                    for p in 0..<polygonPointCount {
                        let mp: MKMapPoint = polygonPoints.unsafelyUnwrapped()[polygonPointCount]
                        if p == 0 {
                            mpr.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(mp.x), y: CGFloat(mp.y)), transform: .identity)
                        }
                        else {
                            mpr.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(mp.x), y: CGFloat(mp.y)), transform: .identity)
                        }
                    }

                    if mpr.contains(mapPointAsCGP, using: .winding, transform: .identity) {
                        print("test")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

I'm not sure why they have the if statement there

```
if (overlay is MKPolygon)
```

because this would never be called since its an array of mkoverlay.

Answer (score 6):

I found that doing it this way is a lot better than relying on the touch event methods.

> For your question about:
>
> ```
> if (overlay is MKPolygon)
> ```
>
> We need to cast the overlay to a polygon so we can get access to the
>   points array, and rebuild the path. Although in my method below,
>   you'll only need access to the points array is the renderer.path is
>   nil. Since I'm using the overlays that are currently on the
>   map, I'm confident that the path is not nil.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapTapped(_:)))

    self.map.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func mapTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let point = gesture.location(in: self.map)

    let coordinate = self.map.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: nil)

    let mappoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate)

    for overlay in self.map.overlays {

        if let polygon = overlay as? MKPolygon {

            guard let renderer = self.map.renderer(for: polygon) as? MKPolygonRenderer else { continue }

            let tapPoint = renderer.point(for: mappoint)

            if renderer.path.contains(tapPoint) {

                print("Tap was inside this polygon")

                break // If you have overlapping overlays then you'll need an array of overlays which the touch is in, so remove this line.
            }

            continue
        }

        if let circle = overlay as? MKCircle {

            let centerMP = MKMapPointForCoordinate(circle.coordinate)

            let distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(mappoint, centerMP) // distance between the touch point and the center of the circle

            if distance <= circle.radius {

                print("Tap was inside this circle")

                break // If you have overlapping overlays then you'll need an array of overlays which the touch is in, so remove this line.
            }

            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both if statements are always false no matter where i tap. Overlay is type MKRoutePolyline and therefore the if let polygon = overlay as? MKPolygon is never true

Comment: Try just changing every occurrence of `MKPolygon` with `MKPolyline`.

Comment: I think you need to change the `toCoordinateFrom: nil` to your mkmapview (for me its `toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView`, otherwise it can't convert the tap position correctly.

Comment: I understand what you are saying @Milly, for the purpose of this example the map view's bounds spanned the entire screen, so using the default coordinate scheme, by putting `nil` in that function, was fine. If your map view's origin isn't at `x:0, y:0` then you should pass the map view as the view. I should remind you that this is just an example of how to do this, and should be used as a guide, not rewritten word for word. It is the programmer's responsibility to understand the code he is writing and to implement it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the info, now I understand properly!

Comment: I needed support for MKMultiPolygonRenderer as well as MKPolygonRenderer. They both inherit from MKOverlayPathRenderer which is all that is needed for the point(for:) and path.contains() portions of the code so it worked well for my use case.